# What is pseudo expression in eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

Documentation if full of use of this term, e.g.

> ```
> Pseudo expression providing partial reduction operations
> ```

> ```
> Pseudo expression providing matrix output with given format
> ```

but I can not find what it means.

Comment: Look up "expression template programming" and see if that explains it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what the Eigen documentation refers to as "pseudo expressions" are actually instances of "[expression templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates)".

Use of expression templates is a common technique in C++ when implementing things like math libraries, or really libraries in any domain where it is expected that users will concatenate together multiple computations to build up a value.

The idea of expression templates is that they are a way of deferring a computation until the computation is actually needed and allowing an additional degree of control over how the computation is actually carried out e.g. you may not need to allocate memory for a temporary possibly large object if the whole computation can be carried out item by item without altering the input arguments.

Anyway as far as being a user of Eigen goes, you do not really need to understand its use of expression templates except for one detail. Never ever write code that looks likes this:

```
auto to_canonical_coords = get_rotation_matrix(theta) * get_translation_matrix(offset);
```

The problem is with doing type deduction on an operation, `operator*` here, which returns an expression template instance. Expression template instances are intended to be ephemeral; such an assignment will assign an expression template instance to a variable where it may outlive objects it refers to by reference or cause other problems. Instead write the above like

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3> to_canonical_coords = get_rotation_matrix(theta) * get_translation_matrix(offset);
```

or the equivalent using a type alias for `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>`.

The Eigen documentation mentions the issue [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). Also I believe Scott Meyers discusses this issue generally in *Effective Modern C++* somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I think an example is a good way of showing off how it works. Imagine a code snippet like this:

```
void print_types(const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>& test) {
    std::cout << typeid(test).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(test.transpose()).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(test.transpose().eval()).name() << "\n";
}
```

Without the expression template programming Eigen does, you'd expect all three of these to print out the same thing: `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>`.

But the transpose operation doesn't actually *need* to be evaluated until it's being used - like if you were to do `A.T * B`, you wouldn't actually ever need to store the transposed `A` matrix, you could just change the order of how you multiply entries. So the actual demangled result of the second printout is `Eigen::Transpose<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>>`. The `Eigen::Transpose<...>` behaves very similarly to the normal `Eigen::Matrix` but doesn't actually require computing the transpose. For simple 3x3 matrices it's probably not a huge improvement most of the time, but for giant matrices there can be a very large performance gains by skipping the calculation.

Calling `.eval()` (like in the third printout) will convert any intermediate Eigen types back into the actual matrix type (by actually doing the calculation), so the third line will print the same `Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>`.

This works with other expressions too, like for `typeid(test * test + test).name()`, you'll see:

```
Eigen::CwiseBinaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_sum_op<double, double>, Eigen::Product<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3>, 0> const, Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3, 0, 3, 3> const>
```

which allows Eigen to better optimize how the final result gets computed but skipping any intermediate calculations.

I hope this makes sense, feel free to comment if not!